# svn+ssh and TortoiseSVN: Network connection closed unexpectedly

Tags: ssh, svn, tortoise-svn

I have a Windows machine with **PuTTY** and **TortoiseSVN** installed, and the following content on the Settings > Network > SSH CLient box:

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe" -l <right_user> -pw <right_password>
```

It works ok and I can checkout and update easily through it from `svn+ssh://<right_server>/<folder>`.

I got a freshly installed Windows notebook, plugged into the same network, and replicated, as far as I know, the settings on it (installed PuTTY, configured the SSH client line the same way), but it keep telling me the connection was expectedly closed.

As all tutorials I've seen so far veer away from the working settings I have in the working machine (no mention to TortoisePlink.exe line above), and involve PuTTYGen and other stuff I don't quite remember doing in the first time.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

1. "-l  -pw " options does not assume using private-key authentication, thus all PuTTYGen-related themes are out of interest for you
2. You can carefully re-read [SSH HowTo](https://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto_logemann.html) from TortoiseSVN site in the section "SSH key generation and connection check (client)", skipping key-related steps of configuration for **Putty** (user+pass will work too), test you connection and show any output if it'll fail

Comment: I tested connecting through PuTTY, providing _<right_user>_ and _<right_password>_, and I got to the shell as expected from both machines. I believe this kind of rules out any firewall or wrong settings related issues, right?

Comment: @FernandoD'Andrea - in such case, yes most probably

Comment: Solved: changed SSH Client setting from:
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe" -l <right_user> -pw <right_password>

to: 

plink.exe -l <right_user> -pw <right_password>

I still don't why, but I know PuTTY has to be installed to the system. It worked with version 0.72.